# Safari only showing one option in select element

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm creating a web site to add statistics from multiple games. The first part reads json files which contain the stats (multiple files per game) and populates an HTML select element for the user to select which games to include in the stats (allowing user to select multiple games). It's working in Chrome and Edge on my computers, but in Safari (iPhone) only one of the games shows as an option (the 4th of 5 games). Below is the function to read the files.
Why would this not be working in Safari? I'm not sure if it has to do with the await / async or something else.

```
jsonFiles = ['file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json'];

async function readGames() {
    let games = {};
    for (let file of jsonFiles) {
        let playlist;
        let gameDate;
        let response = await fetch(file);
        let data = await response.json();
        playlist = data.playlist;
        gameDate = (new Date(playlist.slice(playlist.indexOf('(')+1, playlist.indexOf(')'))).getTime())/10000;
        if (!(gameDate in games)) games[gameDate] = playlist;
    }
    //Remove previous options in the select element
    while(gamesSelect.firstChild) {
        gamesSelect.removeChild(gamesSelect.firstChild);
    }
    const gameValues = Object.values(games);
    for (let game of gameValues) {
        let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute("value", game);
        option.innerHTML = game;
        gamesSelect.append(option);
    }
}
```

Comment: What iOS version are you using? You're using a number of ES6 features, Safari has been slow to implement some of them.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with `gameDate`, and for some reason you're getting the same date for all of them.

Comment: Can you show example values of `playlist`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. The date for each game is different - examples of playlist are "Damascus @ Kennedy (12-20-2021)", "Wheaton @ Damascus (12-10-2021)". I'm using iOS 15.2 on my iPhone, and my suspicion is that I'm using some features that Safari hasn't implemented but don't know which.

Comment: `12-20-2021` is not a standard JS date format, so `new Date()` may not parse it properly.

Comment: Parsing non-standard dates is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Looks like that's it - it's returning NaN for gameDate. Thanks!